# Spring Security: authentication page permitAll seems to be ignored

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, authorization

I am writing an application using Spring Security. 
I've implemented my custom UserDetails, UserDetailsService, AccessDecisionVoter and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
I want to permit unauthorized users to access the `/authenthication/login` page to log in, but every other access to a page needs to be handled by the custom AccessDecisionVoter.
My custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(value = "security")
public class Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authentication/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
        ;
    }


    @Bean
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters =
                Arrays.asList(new AccessDecisionVoterImpl());
        return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        try {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsServiceImpl;
    }

}
```

I have defined several roles in my database. The `vote` method in my custom AccessDecisionVoter retrieves the permissions of the User that is logged in and grants or denies access, based on that and the URL + httpMethod.

Problem:
However when I send a POST to the /authentication/login with the username and password my code gives me a NullPointerException in the custom AccessDecisionVoter: the username (retrieved via the `authentication.getPrincipal();` returns anonymousUser, which results in the NullPointer later in the code. But I don't understand why the `vote` method gets called anyway since the configuration file told Spring to permittAll accesses to /authentication/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the way you have it set up, permitAll just makes it so that all requests are allowed (even unauthenticated ones) but it doesn't disable the security chain for that request, it will still try to process through them all. If you just want to bypass all the security, the approach i usually use is to override the webSecurity config method and add the exception cases there, like so:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
{
    webSecurity
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/authentication/login**");
}
```